# Flask-Dance and Error: redirect_uri_mismatch

Tags: python-3.x, flask, oauth-2.0, flask-dance

I'm following the [example](https://flask-dance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstarts/google.html) in the docs:

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for
from flask_dance.contrib.google import make_google_blueprint, google

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = "supersekrit"
blueprint = make_google_blueprint(
    client_id="my-key-here",
    client_secret="my-secret-here",
    scope=[
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
    ]
)
app.register_blueprint(blueprint, url_prefix="/login")

@app.route("/")
def index():
    if not google.authorized:
        return redirect(url_for("google.login"))
    resp = google.get("/oauth2/v2/userinfo")
    assert resp.ok, resp.text
    return "You are {email} on Google".format(email=resp.json()["email"])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

I've configured my Web Client app in Google developer console to only accept HTTPS using `https://www.example.com/login/google/authorized` endpoint.

After I try to start the whole auth process I get this:

```
Error: redirect_uri_mismatch
```

I can see in the request that Flask-Dance is sending `http://www.example.com/login/google/authorized` (using HTTP, not HTTPS). Is there a way to tell Flask-Dance to use HTTPS instead? I have my develop environment configured for HTTPS as well.

Comment: What did you eventually do to make this work?

Comment: @stasdeep I ended up using `OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT` and `OAUTHLIB_RELAX_TOKEN_SCOPE` to `'1'`

Answer (score 2):

If Flask-Dance is generating a redirect URL using HTTP, that means that Flask (not Flask-Dance) believes that the incoming request is using HTTP. (Check [`request.scheme`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.Request.scheme) to confirm that.) If the incoming request is actually using HTTPS, then Flask is getting confused somewhere, mostly like due to a proxy. Check [the Flask docs on proxy setups](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/deploying/wsgi-standalone/#deploying-proxy-setups) for more information.

Once Flask understands that the incoming request is using HTTPS, then Flask-Dance will automatically understand that redirect URL should also use HTTPS.

(Source: I am the author of Flask-Dance)

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your app.wsgi like this and you will be good to go:

```
app.wsgi_app = ProxyFix(app.wsgi_app, x_proto=1, x_host=1)
```